# How can I access to a value in Excel using Pandas with subcolumns?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to read a value from a cell which is located in a subcolumn of a big column. I want to read it by using the string labels and not the integers. [image: my excel]

How can I access the value '%' of Product1 in 'Step1' using df.loc?

I am trying

```
df.loc['Step1', 'Product1','%']
```

but it doesnt function. Thank you for your help

Comment: What's a subcolumn?

Comment: under product1 are the subcolumns quantity, %  and priority

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you load the data and what you get as a result? (e.g. df.describe())

Comment: Still a column in its own right.

Comment: Use tuples,  `df.loc[:, ('Product1', '%')]`